# Deleted all the content... but it's all still there?

Tags: theming

I wanted to start from scratch so deleted all the content from my Drupal site. Now I am getting the following error:

Notice: Undefined index: name in system_sort_modules_by_info_name() (line 949 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/modules/system/system.admin.inc).

Also, even though I deleted all the content, it is still appearing under the Menus. Do I need to manually remove it from the menus as well? I was hoping that deleting the nodes/content would automatically remove it from the menus...

I deleted the content by going to Administration » Content, selected all the pages/nodes and them selected the "delete selected content" option.

Comment: Did you delete the database?  Delete the content using the Drupal admin interface?  Delete the files?  Please be more specific.

Comment: how did you delete the content?

Comment: I deleted the content by going to Administration » Content, selected all the pages/nodes and them selected the "delete selected content" option.

Comment: Try to flush all caches.

Comment: In, /admin/config/development/performance?
Did that a few times already but still no luck :(

Comment: By the way, it is just the navigation menu that is displaying the old content (when I go to structure/menus/list links). In preview mode, they are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

That `Undefined index: name in system_sort_modules_by_info_name()` error sounds like a broken module not defining its name in its .info file

One possibility is from coder/coder_sniffer/Test/bad.info

see: http://drupal.org/node/1015368